# Cómo poner barras de error en la gráfica del eje secundario usando ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo estos datos:

```
df1 <- data.frame(level = c(1, 2, 3),
                  MeP = c(18.94, 21.14, 24.25),
                  seP = c(5.41, 5.36, 5.38),
                  MeI = c(9.16, 10.04, 12.15),
                  seI = c(2.92, 2.90, 2.91))
```

Y estoy usando este código para graficar

```
scaleFactor <- max(df1$MeI) / max(df1$MeP)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = level, width = 0.4)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = MeI), fill = "blue",
             position = position_nudge(x = -0.4)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = MeI-seI, ymax = MeI+seI),
                  stat = "identity",
                  width = 0.15,
                  size=0.8,
                  position = position_dodge()) +
    geom_col(aes(y = MeP*scaleFactor), fill="red") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "MeI",
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="MeP")) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = MeP-seP, ymax = MeP+seP),
                  stat = "identity",
                  width = 0.15,
                  size = 0.8,
                  position = position_nudge(x = -0.05))
```

Y esto es lo que consigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo debo hacer para que las barras de error aparezcan donde le corresponden?
Qué debo hacer para que se vean completas?
Pensé que con `position=position_dodge()` funcionaría pero veo que no.
Por último, cómo puedo ajustar el color usando la paleta RColorBrewer?
Intenté poninedo `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")` en el código pero asignó un color a cada barra, sino que puso todo en gris.

Answer (score 2):

Gráficos con dos ejes "y" no son, generalmente, la mejor opción para
mostrar datos de manera fiel.
Algunas consideraciones sobre porqué evitar esos gráficos:
[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/16978684)  y en este [link](https://www.lri.fr/%7Eisenberg/publications/papers/Isenberg_2011_ASO.pdf) recomendado por el autor del comentario anterior.

Un efecto gráfico similar a lo que está en tu código puede ser logrado cambiando el formato de la tabla e incluyendo "MeP" y "MeI" en la misma columna:

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 |> pivot_longer(cols = c(MeP, MeI))
```

Ya que una de las variables es transformada, eso puede realizarse sustituyendo los valores directamente en la tabla:

```
mepscale <- df1$MeP*scaleFactor

df2[df2$name == "MeP", "value"] <- mepscale
```

El siguiente código debe producir un gráfico similar al quieres elaborar:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = factor(level), y = value, width = 0.4, fill = name)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - seI, ymax = value + seI),
                  width = 0.15,
                  size = 0.8,
                  position = position_dodge(0.4)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la solución. En mi caso es necesario indicar las unidades del eje secundario; seguiré buscando cómo hacerlo.